# How to get orders count sub-queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have some difficuties to get orders count with the following SQL query:

```
select
  d.id,
  d.title,
  count(distinct o.id)
from store s
    left join `order` o on o.store_id = s.id
    left join order_product op on op.order_id=o.id
    left join store_product sp on sp.id = op.product_id
    left join product p on p.id = sp.product_id
    left join department_category_to_entity dce1 on dce1.entity_type IN ('Product') and dce1.entity_id = p.id
    left join department_category_to_entity dce2 on op.status != 'replaced' and
                                                       op.replacement_id is null and
                                                       dce2.entity_type IN ('StoreProduct') and
                                                       dce2.entity_id = sp.id
    left join department_category_to_entity dce3 on op.status = 'replaced' and
                                                       op.replacement_id is not null and
                                                       dce3.entity_type IN ('StoreProduct') and
                                                       dce3.entity_id = op.replacement_id
    left join department_category dc on dc.id = p.department_category_id or
                                           dc.id = dce1.category_id or
                                           dc.id = dce2.category_id or
                                           dc.id = dce3.category_id
    left join department d on d.id = dc.department_id


where d.id is not null

group by d.id;
```

Is it possible to get orders count without sub-queries or to get correct count of orders? Please, help... Thank you!

Comment: You don't have any subqueries...

Comment: @Nick, Ok then, but I'm getting incorrect count of orders. Can you tell me what's wrong with query?

Comment: There's no way of doing that without seeing your table structures and sample data...

Answer (score 0):

- You have `LEFT JOIN`, which says to keep looking even if there is no row in the 'right' table.  But, on the other hand, you are `GROUPing BY` a column in the last of a chain of `LEFT JOINs`!  Perhaps you meant `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`??
- Saying `where d.id is not null` is roughly equivalent to saying "Oops, all those `LEFT JOINs` could have been `JOINs`.
- With `GROUP BY` and `JOINs` (`LEFT` or otherwise), you are doing an "inflate-deflate".  What logically happens is all the `JOINing` is done to build a huge intermediate table with all the valid combinations.  *Then* the `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` are done.  This tends to make the `COUNTs` (and `SUMs`, etc) have bigger values than expected.
- What's the most direct route to get from `department` to `order`?  It does not seem to involve `store`, so get rid of that table.
- Are other tables irrelevant?

Even after addressing those issue, you still may be getting the wrong value.  Please provide, for starters, `SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table.